# Imputing and handling class imbalance

Tags: unbalanced-classes, data-imputation

I have data with missing values. My $y$ is imbalanced (20% to 80%).

a) is it at all possible to balance (e. via Smote) and Impute (e. via Mice) or will the results become too unreliable?

b) if a) is possible => first Impute and then Balance or the other way around?

Comment: 20% to 80% is hardly imbalanced.  These rebalancing methods are very, very overused.  It is almost certain that you are better off working with your data as is.  What you do with the missing values depends on the nature of your problem, are you after a predictive model, or are you trying to do inference and interpret the parameter estimates?

Comment: thanks for your answer....getting more concrete it is a medical-psychiatric database of 400 subjects and the goal is to identify the most defining (categorical) variables for a certain (violent) behavior. I work with matlab => using the raw data set lead to the programm to put all observations in 1 class (with an far worse AUC)....after balancing this worked well

Answer (score 1):

Balance is not a consideration for imputation. Imputation will not magically balance the data unless the design was to be balanced, yet there was severe missingness-at-random.

Does balance even matter? For most analyses, the only adverse effect of imbalance is a modest reduction in power. Imputation *does* address that. If the data are 20/80, the final imputation may still be 20/80 but most importantly, you will increase your N. 20% of N=100 complete cases may result in an underpowered analysis, 20% of N=300 in imputed dataset(s) looks a lot better.

To calculate the correct variance of an analysis, you must treat the imputed dataset as a "final" dataset. So if any algorithms are to be applied to match or weight, do so after simulating the missing values.